# DNS for websites not updating in some browsers like brave/chrome/edge but works fine in opera/firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, dns, browser, brave

I recently moved my sites from digitalocean to vpsdime. So I had to point to a different dns server. But for some reason Brave/Chrome/Edge don't want to update the dns. Everything works just fine in Firefox and Opera. When I do a dns lookup at https://mxtoolbox.com/DNSLookup.aspx I get the correct ip address do obviously the dns is pointing to the correct place. The strange thing is that it is only for a couple of the sites. A couple of them are working in all browsers and a couple of them are not working in just Brave/Chrome/Edge. They also don't work in other devices. I've tried my laptop and phone as well ad I am having the same result with the same browsers/sites. I've never come across this issue before where some browsers have updated the dns but others haven't. I have tried flushing the dns in the browser and in windows but no luck.

```
ipconfig /flushdns
brave://net-internals/#dns
brave://net-internals/#sockets
```

So then I decided to just erase all browsing history but that didn't work either. It has been a couple of days and every time try to load my sites I just get

```
This site can’t be reached
DNS address could not be found. Diagnosing the problem.
DNS_PROBE_POSSIBLE
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? Do I just need to wait for longer? It has been a couple of days already.

Comment: DNS_PROBE_POSSIBLE means that the browser is unable to establish a connection to the DNS servers. Try: (1) Reboot a couple of times (the oldest remedy), (2) Try Chrome in Incognito mode.

Comment: @harrymc I tried both of those things and no luck. It's worth noting that I have tried different devices and the same thing happens. I updated the question with this info. I think I am getting DNS_PROBE_POSSIBLE because I deleted the domains under digitaloceans nameserver. I'm willing to bet if I set up a domain under their nameserver again it would probably still be pointed there. I think the dns is just not updating to the new nameservers.

Comment: Speculating wildly I wonder if the browsers that are not updated are using DoH and the server they are using is caching the old result still?

Comment: Ya so I just created a domain record under DigitalOceans nameservers and it is still pointing there. I haven't deleted the droplet yet so all of the site conents are still there. So for some reason for these couple of domains the cached values are not updating to the new nameservers.

Comment: DNS updates can be long. Maybe test again tomorrow.